# Stable partition std::vector by the parity of the element's original position

Tags: c++, algorithm, functional-programming, std

I would like to partition a `std::vector` by the parity of the element's original index in the container. In other words, I would like to divide it into two halves: the first would contain all even indexed elements and the second would contain all odd indexed elements.

The ordering relations between the elements are irrelevant, only the position in the original vector is what matters.

I would like to achieve this effect with the **standard algorithms** and lambdas, preferably in situ. I can do it with a regular `for` loop.

### Example

Let us assume we have a vector of elements `a b c d e f`. The desired the partitioning is `a c e b d f`. The first (`a`), third (`c`) and fifth (`e`) element is moved to the front, while the second (`b`), fourth (`d`) and sixth (`f`) elements is moved to the back.

### My Attempts

I have an object resembling this one:

```cpp
struct T {
    int x;
};
```

I was able to partition it by a field value like so:

```cpp
std::vector<T> ts {{1}, {2}, {4}, {3}, {6}, {5}};
auto predicate = [](const T& t) {
    return t.x % 2 == 1;
};
std::stable_partition(ts.begin(), ts.end(), predicate);
```

The result is `1 3 5 2 4 6`. I want the partitioning to return `1 4 6 2 3 5`.

I tried to define the `predicate` as

```cpp
auto predicate = [](const std::vector<T>::const_iterator& t)
    return t->x % 2 == 1;
};
```

But it does not compile and it clearly does not make any sense.

To illustrate my problem, I have written a `for` loop which does this partitioning, although not in a stable manner.

```cpp
for (auto i = ts.begin() + 1, j = ts.begin() + 2; j != ts.end(); i += 1, j += 2) {
    std::swap(*i, *j);
}
```

### Summary

Is it possible to achieve it with `std` algorithms, or do I need to resort to a standard loop?

Comment: just to be sure: Do you understand why you get `1 3 5 2 4 6` as result and not `1 4 6 2 3 5` ?

Comment: Yes, I do and I agree that the wording might imply otherwise. I just wanted to show something that at least compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c++11, use a counter to act as index to verify if it is even or odd.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct T {
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<T> ts {{1}, {2}, {4}, {3}, {6}, {5}};
    int counter =0;
    auto predicate = [&counter]() {
        ++counter;
        return (counter % 2 == 1);
    };
    std::stable_partition(ts.begin(), ts.end(), predicate);

    for(auto i: ts)
        std::cout << i.x << ", ";

}
```

Comment: is `stable_partition` guaranteed to visit the elements in order? I think with parallel execution this assumption breaks

Comment: Wow, that's great! We could even use a mutable lambda and move the declaration of the counter into the lambda to keep it clean: `[c = 0](const T&) mutable { return c++ % 2 == 0; }`

Answer (score 3):

Vector stores its data in linear array. You can use this knowledge.

Make lambda as predicate which captures a pointer to first item of vector,
and takes its argument **by reference** to T, to refer an original stored element of vector. 
Then you can find out if index is even/odd by simple pointer arithmetic:

```
struct T {
    int x;
};
int main() {
    std::vector<T> ts {{1}, {2}, {4}, {3}, {6}, {5}};

    auto pred = [beg = &(*ts.begin())](T& elem) {
        return (&elem-beg) % 2 == 0;
    };

    std::stable_partition(ts.begin(), ts.end(), pred);
    for (T t : ts)
        std::cout << t.x << std::endl;
    // 1,4,6,2,3,5
}
```

Comment: Nice! Making `beg` and `elem` `const&` could be a small improvement: `auto pred = [beg = ts.front()](const T& elem) {
        return std::distance(&beg, &elem) % 2 == 0;
    };`

Comment: @TedLyngmo, are assignments in the capture groups copies or references? I would expect your lambda to crash (but it does not, tested). I thought that assigning to `beg` would copy the value (and therefore change the address), causing the whole pointer math to fail with a 50% probability.

Comment: @MaciejStanek You're right, that doesn't seem correct... `auto pred = [&beg = std::as_const(ts.front())](const T& elem) {
        return std::distance(&beg, &elem) % 2 == 0;
    };` would be correct though.